# IEnumerable: Get all before the last that matches a predicate

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<int>` like this, only longer:

```
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

and now I want to return all elements before the last non-zero value:

```
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0
```

It seems `sequence.Last()` doesn't help here, because it returns the last occurrence, not the index of the last occurrence.

I had thought to use

```
var lastIndex = sequence.LastIndex(x=>x!=0);
subsequence = sequence.Take(lastIndex);
```

which would work in the general case, but `LastIndex` doesn't exist, or

```
var last = sequence.Last(y=>y!=0);
subsequence = sequence.TakeWhile(x=>x!=last)
```

which would work on the example, but not in the general case, where there may be duplicated non-zero values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
var allDataBeforeLastNonZero= sequence.GetRange(0,sequence.FindLastIndex(x=>x!=0));
```

Comment: This is by far the least ugliest solution, but it assumes `sequence` to be a `List<T>`. Anyway +1.

Comment: It is an `IEnumerable<int>` so it would have to be converted to a list first.

Comment: Since you will _have_ to walk over whole IEnumerable anyway - no harm to convert it to list first.

Comment: @Evk the amount of memory needed for the problem is enough to contain the largest sequence between non-zero elements, whereas this uses the amount of memory needed to hold the entire sequence, and also can't give any results until the very last element has been read. That certainly could be a harm if the sequence is large enough.

Answer (score 5):

> would work in the general case, but LastIndex doesn't exist

No, but you can find it with:

```
var lastIndex = sequence
  .Select((x, i) => new {El = x, Idx = i})
  .Where(x => x.El != 0)
  .Select(x => x.Idx).Last();
```

If you need to work with `IQueryable<T>` that's about as good as you can get.

It has a few problems. For one thing it scans through the sequence twice, and who is to say the sequence even allow that. We can do better but we'll have to buffer, though not necessarily buffer the whole thing:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> BeforeLastMatch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
  return BeforeLastMatchImpl(source, predicate);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> BeforeLastMatchImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  var buffer = new List<T>();
  foreach(T item in source)
  {
    if (predicate(item) && buffer.Count != 0)
    {
      foreach(T allowed in buffer)
      {
          yield return allowed;
      }
      buffer.Clear();
    }
    buffer.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Call `sequence.BeforeLastMatch(x => x != 0)` and you get `5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0`

If you really need it to work with both `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` that can be handled too, but it's a bit more complicated. Don't bother if you know you'll only ever have in-memory `IEnumerable`. (Also some providers have different support for different features so you might be forced to do the in-memory version above anyway):

```
private class ElementAndIndex<T>
{
  public T Element { get; set; }
  public int Index { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<T> BeforeLastMatch<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
  // If source is actually an in-memory enumerable, the other method will be more efficient,
  // so use it instead.
  var asEnum = source as EnumerableQuery<T>;
  if (asEnum != null && asEnum.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
  {
    // On any other IQueryable calling `AsEnumerable()` will force it
    // to be loaded into memory, but on an EnumerableQuery it just
    // unwraps the wrapped enumerable this will chain back to the
    // contained GetEnumerator.
    return BeforeLastMatchImpl(source.AsEnumerable(), predicate.Compile()).AsQueryable();
  }

  // We have a lambda from (T x) => bool, and we need one from
  // (ElementAndIndex<T> x) => bool, so build it here.

  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ElementAndIndex<T>));
  var indexingPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<ElementAndIndex<T>, bool>>(
    Expression.Invoke(predicate, Expression.Property(param, "Element")),
    param
  );

  return source.Take( // We're going to Take based on the last index this finds.
    source
      // Elements and indices together
      .Select((x, i) => new ElementAndIndex<T>{ Element = x, Index = i}) 
      // The new predicate we created from that passed to us.
      .Where(indexingPredicate)
      // The last matching element.
      .Select(x => x.Index).Last());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this one is the best way I think.

Comment: It'll be easier to use a queue for the buffer instead.

Comment: @JeffMercado not really. If we were using a queue we could do a bunch of `Pop()`s but it would be more performant to `foreach` and then `Clear()` and if we do that with a queue then literally the only difference left is the word `Add` gets replaced with the word `Push`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The predicate the OP was using was `x => x != 0` and they wanted the results of `5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0` which is the sequence before the last match of that predicate, which is what the above produces.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are more efficent approaches but this one is readable, isn't it?

```
var allBeforeLastNonZero = sequence
    .Reverse()                // look from the end
    .SkipWhile(i => i == 0)   // skip the zeros
    .Skip(1)                  // skip last non-zero
    .Reverse();               // get original order
```

Comment: If the given `IEnumerable<T>` is not an `ICollection<T>` and the sequence is quite long it will take a lot of time and memory to do the `.Reverse()` call.

Comment: Reverse() doesn't reverse the collection. It creates a reverse iterator, that goes from the end of collection.

Comment: @Dmitry: true, but Oliver is right, if the input sequence is not a collection the [`Buffer` used](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ed118118b642d9d4,references) will create a new one to be able to [loop it backwards](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e247ee4147678571,references). So If the input sequence is a collection the first `Reverse` doesn't need to create a temp-array but the second `Reverse` needs it for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for refs too. Looks like the best solution is a good old for(;;) loop

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your list into a string and use `String.Trim`:

```
var str = String.Join(",", myInputArray);
var result = str.TrimEnd(',', '0').Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
result.RemoveAt(result.Count - 1);
```

Have to admit seems a bit ugly, but it should work.

Comment: Now it's even more ugly but you got my upvote for that creative one I didn't think of

Comment: @fubo What was your suggestion on removing the last item? Just of curiosity. I didn´t find any solution which isn´t ugly also.

Comment: I see no better approach since there is a special treatment for the last character required :( Tim's approach also requires the `.Skip(1) ` for that

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<int> source = new List<int> {5,0,0, 4,0,0,3, 0, 0};
List<int> result = new List<int>();
List<int> buffer = new List<int>();
foreach (var i in source)
{
    buffer.Add(i);
    if (i != 0)
    {
        result.AddRange(buffer);
        buffer.Clear();
    }
}
```