# How do you remove trailing objects from a list with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects with properties and I want to remove all the trailing objects with (say) a value of `0` in LINQ.

```
public class Object
{
    public Object(){}

    public int Property {get; set;}
}
```

and if I have a list of objects:

```
new Object(){ Property = 1};
new Object(){ Property = 0};
new Object(){ Property = 9};
new Object(){ Property = 7};
new Object(){ Property = 0}; // "trailing zero"
new Object(){ Property = 0}; // "trailing zero"
new Object(){ Property = 0}; // "trailing zero"
```

How would I go about removing the "trailing zeros" in this list? I don't want to remove all properties with a zero, but I want to remove any objects from the list with a property value of zero if it it is not later followed by a property value of something greater.

Comment: what kind of collection do you have?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am currently working with a List<Object>, although I can change that if it would make my life easier.

Comment: You don't. You create a new Enumerable that does not include those elements. `var noZeroList = mylist.Where(i=>i.Property != 0);`

Comment: What did you try? Where did you run into trouble? Why do you need to use LINQ? Do you often use LINQ to alter existing collections? Do you know what kind of container class your list of objects is in, or as suggested in your question, do you just call a bunch of constructors and throw the instances to the winds, like butterflies in Hyde Park?

Comment: I hope this class isn't named `Object` in your original code.

Comment: Not great, but `var result = list.Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x.Property == 0).Reverse();`

Comment: Almost the same as [IEnumerable: Get all before the last that matches a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802341/ienumerable-get-all-before-the-last-that-matches-a-predicate/40803300#40803300)

Comment: @Amy All classes should be named Object and all properties should be named Property; this is inherently self-documentating and enforces the Do One Thing rule.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks, that gave me a good chuckle.

Comment: @EdPlunkett lol, I assumed people would get the point with all the instances being magically tossed to the wind. Clearly I'd be asking other questions if this were my actual code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard solution for sequences of finite size - reverse, remove from start, reverse:

```
   var withoutTail = sequence
       .Reverse()
       .SkipWhile( x => x == 0) // whatever condition you need
       .Reverse();
```

This is very non-optimal, so if you actually have real collection (i.e. `List`) it would be better to just remove items starting from last index.

Answer (score 4):

Write an extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TrimTrailing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
                                                 Predicate<T> test)
    {

        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
        if (test == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(test));

        var buf = new List<T>();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (test(item))
            {
                buf.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (T bufferedItem in buf)
                {
                    yield return bufferedItem;
                }
                buf.Clear();
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you have an `IEnumerable<Object>` called `l`, you would call `TrimTrailing` using

```
var trimmed = l.TrimTrailing(o => o.Property == 0);
```

Be careful with this, though: in the worst case, it buffers all the items from `items` and then throws away the buffer.

Comment: i like this for readability compared to reverse + skip + reverse

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate your list backwards removing any `0` entries and stop either at the beginning of the list or the `Property != 0`.

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var item = list[i];
    if (item.Property == 0)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will allow for a single pass through your list.

Comment: why not just `if(list[i].Property != 0) break; list.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: @juharr sure - thats any reasonable refactoring.

Comment: @juharr sometimes its best to reverse it to make it more readable for the use case.

Comment: feels like too much code and the `i > 0` seems a bit off `for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >=0 && list[i].Property == 0; i--) list.RemoveAt(i);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindLastIndex` to find the last non-`0` index, and `Take` the elements up to that.

```
var result = list.Take(list.FindLastIndex(x => x.Property != 0) + 1);
```

Comment: That would only return the first item for the example.

Comment: @juharr: Thats true, I see it now. Thanks. Updated answer.